# Procedure 'login' not present - Magja

Tags: api, soap

Hi I am using magja which is Java Connector for magento api. https://github.com/magja/magja I am not getting any response of the issue I posted on their issues list.

And I am not expert in java and I am newbie to eclipse too, can anyone guide me how I can debug my code, and what type of error is this, below is the error I am getting currently

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Procedure 'login' not present
    at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.<init>(MagentoSoapClient.java:104)
    at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.getInstance(MagentoSoapClient.java:84)
    at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.getInstance(MagentoSoapClient.java:60)
    at com.google.code.magja.magento.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:24)
    at com.google.code.magja.magento.Connection.main(Connection.java:27)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Procedure 'login' not present
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:540)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:521)
    at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.login(MagentoSoapClient.java:185)
    at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.<init>(MagentoSoapClient.java:101)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using soap v2 api of magento, but magja works with v1 api. So getting back to v1 api resolved my problem.